# docker-compose ps does not show running services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a docker-compose stack launched on a remote machine, through gitlab CI/CD (a runner connects to the docker engine on the remote machine and performs the deploy with `docker-compose up -d`).

When I connect to that machine from my laptop, using `eval docker-machine env REMOTE_ADDRESS`, I can see the docker processes running (with `docker ps`), while the services stack appears to be empty (`docker-compose ps`).

I am not able to use `docker-compose down` to stop the stack, and trying `docker-compose up -d` gives me the error

```
ERROR: for feamp_postgres  Cannot create container for service postgres: Conflict. The container name "/feamp_postgres" is already in use by container "40586885...". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

The reverse is also true, I can start the stack from my local laptop (using docker-machine), but then the CI/CD pipeline fails when trying to execute `docker-compose up -d` with the same error.

This happens using the latest versions of docker and docker-compose, both on the laptop (OSX) and on the runner (ubuntu 18.04).

In other circumstances (~10 other projects) this has worked smoothly.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file I am using.

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  web:
    container_name: feamp_web
    restart: always
    image: guglielmo/fpa/feamp:latest
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    environment:
      - ...
    volumes:
      - public:/app/public
      - data:/app/data
      - uwsgi_spooler:/var/lib/uwsgi
      - weblogs:/var/log
    command: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --socket=:8000 ...

  nginx:
    container_name: feamp_nginx
    restart: always
    ...

  postgres:
    container_name: feamp_postgres
    restart: always
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ...

  redis:
    container_name: feamp_redis
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ...

volumes:
    ...

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: webproxy
```

Normally I can up the stack from my local laptop **and** manage it from the CI/CD pipeline on gitlab, or vice-versa.

This diagram should help visualise the situation.

```
                        +-----------------+                          
                        |                 |                          
                        |  Remote server  |                          
                        |                 |                          
                        +----|--------|---+                          
                             |        |                              
                             |        |                              
            docker-compose ps|        |docker-compose up -d          
                             |        |                              
                             |        |                              
+-------------------+        |        |        +--------------------+
|                   |        |        |        |                    |
|  Docker client 1  ---------+        +---------  Docker client 2   |
|                   |                          |                    |
+-------------------+                          +--------------------+
```

Connection to the remote server's docker engine are executed through `docker-machine`.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that specifying the project name when invoking `docker-compose` commands, solves the issue.

This can be done using the `-p` parameter in the command line or the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable, on both *clients*.

For some reasons, this was not needed in previous projects.
It may be a change in docker (I changed from 18 to 19), or something else, I still do not know the details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `docker-compose ps` you can try `docker ps -a` and work from there.

Assuming you are ok simply discarding the containers, you can brute-force removal by calling:

```
docker rm -f 40586885
docker network rm webproxy
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But see, although I can see and manage the docker containers, I cannot handle them through `docker-compose`, while I usually do. There must be something different here, that's locking the *normal* behaviour.

Comment: What does `docker-compose ps -a` give you?

Comment: It gives an empty response.

Comment: And then what does `docker ps -a` give? If it’s also not showing the troublesome container, maybe there’s some sort of corruption and/or you need to either restart docker or do some stuff in the filesystem

Comment: No, it does show the complete stack, with correct container names (`feamp_web`, `feamp_postgres`, and so on, in my case). That's exactly where I'm stuck.

Comment: Just added a diagram in the question above, hope it clarifies, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the project name into .env file

docker compose 3.7, docker latest version (2022-07-17)

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = demo.sitedomain-testing.com
```

The compose project name do not support dots (.).
I just replaced by hifen and it worked well.

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = demo-sitedomain-testing-com
```

In addition, container name also, do not support dots.